# changing columns into a new data frame in a special way in R

Tags: r

I could really use some help as a new b in R, I have a set of column data with over a thousand (1000) rows, in this form:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

I want to use the data to build a neural network, and i would like it to look like this (in a form of a data frame):

```
x1  x2  x3  x4  y
1   2   3   4   5
2   3   4   5   6
3   4   5   6   7
4   5   6   7   8
5   6   7   8   9
6   7   8   9   10
```

Is there any simple way i can go about it or i will have to subset each till the end? Any help? I would be glad it the codes could have some comments for understanding, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another option is `guyrot()` from `wavethresh` package

```
library(wavethresh)
ncol <- 5
sapply(0:5, function(x) guyrot(a,-x)[1:6])
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
#[2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7
#[3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
#[4,]    4    5    6    7    8    9
#[5,]    5    6    7    8    9   10
#[6,]    6    7    8    9   10    1
```

Comment: had used it in one of my functions some time back! :) @akrun

Comment: @Desdejei you should also look at the function code..it's very intuitive and easy to understand!

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(head(a,5), function(i) i:(i+5)))
```

---

Or another option is `embed`

```
as.data.frame(embed(a, 5)[,5:1])
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  1  2  3  4  5
#2  2  3  4  5  6
#3  3  4  5  6  7
#4  4  5  6  7  8
#5  5  6  7  8  9
#6  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Or `data.frame(lapply(head(a,5), function(i) i:(i+5)))` to produce a data.frame. maybe with `setNames` thrown in for good measure.